# Implementing DI using Unity (design time configuration) in Web API 2

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on implementing DI using Unity in Web API Layer. Following is the error message I am getting while calling the Service -

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "API.Controllers.LeadController", name = "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   Business.ILeadManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are
>   you missing a type mapping?
>
> ---
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving API.Controllers.LeadController,(none)
>
> Resolving parameter "leadManager" of constructor
>   API.Controllers.LeadController(Business.ILeadManager leadManager)
>
> Resolving Business.ILeadManager,(none)

Any suggestions, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your unity configuration is missing a mapping for type `Business.ILeadManager`, so unity does not know which object instance it should create.

There should be an entry for your type like:

```
<register type="Business.ILeadManager" mapTo="MyLeadManagerImplementation" />
```